# Storing pixel coordinates in a matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have to store coordinates of pixels of an image in matrix in form of(x,y). 
The code I am trying is:

```
[x,y]=size(diff_im);
count=0;
for i=1:x
    for j=1:y
        if a(i,j)==0
            count=count+1;
            new_x(count)=j;
            new_y(count)=i;
        end
    end
end
```

Currently I am storing x and y in separate arrays. But I would like to know how to store both x,y values in single matrix.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. `x` and `y` are scalars. Do you mean you want `new_x` and `new_y` to be one matrix? Can you describe exactly what you are trying to do and what output you desire?

Comment: The two matrices here have size `x*y`, what size matrix do you expect? And what you did right now can be done a lot shorter by `new_x,new_y]=meshgrid(1:x,1:y);new_x(a~=0) = 0;new_y(a~=0) = 0;`

Comment: as far as I understood your question, you just want to use `new_xy(count,:) = [j i ];` to store your pairs of values in the rows of an Array or  `new_xy(:,count) = [j; i];` to store them in columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is an array where every row is the x/y coordinate of the pixels that are 0 in `a`, you can use `find`, followed by a catenation.

```
[new_y, new_x]=find(a==0); %// x/y are now correct for plotting onto an image
new_xy = [new_x,new_y];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure of what you want. If all you want is to store couples of new coordinates in a single matrix you can do something very basic like:

```
[x,y]=size(diff_im);
count=0;
for i=1:x
    for j=1:y
        if a(i,j)==0 %what is this line??
            count=count+1;
            A(count,1)=j;
            A(count,2)=i;
        end
    end
end
```

Each new pair of coords can then be retreived by `A(i,:)`